# AWS Forecast Export - Create Only One CSV File?

Tags: amazon-web-services, export, export-to-csv, amazon-forecast

When I am creating an AWS Forecast Export, it creates multiple small CSVs in the S3 bucket. Seemingly 1 for each item_id that I am making predictions for.

My question is, is there a setting I can change to export all of this information as 1 CSV file?

Thanks in advance, I am new to AWS Forecast :)

[image: TOO MANY CSV FILES!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question, looks like the feature is not ready yet. you have to create a separate service with athena to export single csv file. Please refer here from AWS: https://repost.aws/questions/QUMOGKLulFRjuSUTLkJ4B7dQ/aws-forecast-export-create-only-one-csv-file

The AWS Forecast service does not currently have a method to reduce the number of output files using the console, CLI, or the SDK. The service is designed in such a way that it dynamically calculates the number of output CSV files.

A feature request exists for exporting data to a single file but I am unable to provide an ETA of when/if such a feature would be implemented. To work around this, you may consider using the “Improving Forecast Accuracy with Machine Learning” solution (1) to create an aggregated view of all your forecast data (inputs and outputs), query your forecast output within AWS Athena, and then export the query results as a single CSV.

Resources: (1). https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/improving-forecast-accuracy-with-machine-learning/